# How do I read across an array in a different way than I filled it

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, cryptography

In my current program, I am trying to decrypt a string with a very basic cipher. To do this I convert an inputted string into a 2d array of characters, and fill the array ***downwards***. By doing this the actual message can be seen by reading ***across*** the rows. My problem is that I can fill the array correctly but have no idea how to read across the rows and output those values to get the un encrypted message.

The relevant code is as follows

```
    char[][] charArray = new char[column][row];
    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {              
            if (x < input.length()) {
                charArray[i][j] = input.charAt(x);
                outputArea.append("[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]" + charArray[i][j]);
                x++;
            }
            if (x >= input.length()) {
                charArray[i][j] = ' ';
                outputArea.append("[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]" + charArray[i][j]);
                x++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Since I output the same way as I read-in, I just get the string over again.

For example I would like the string ***PNTSLTMAAEEGIXSE*** to display ***PLAINTEXTMESSAGE***

The grid would be as such

P L A I 
N T E X 
T M E S 
S A G E

Comment: Start with the java tutorial [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: Something like for(i=0; i<row*column; i++) { print(char[floor(i/row)][i%column]) } I think floor is in java.math. % is the modulo operator

Answer (score 0):

You would want something like this to get the original string back:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        char c = charArray[j][i];
        System.out.print(c);
    }
}
```

Also, you should have the `x++;` done once; otherwise you will overwrite the last character with a space.

When x = input.length - 1; You x++; then you will go into the next if within the same loop iteration and overwrite the char you just stored.

Have it this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {              
            if (x < input.length()) {
                charArray[i][j] = input.charAt(x);
                outputArea.append("[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]" + charArray[i][j]);
            }
            if (x >= input.length()) {
                charArray[i][j] = ' ';
                outputArea.append("[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]" + charArray[i][j]);
            }

            x++; // have it here outside both if statments
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete code fragment:

```
    String str = "PLAINTEXTMESSAGE";

    // To get the row and column
    double sqrt = Math.sqrt(str.length());
    int row = (int)sqrt; // be careful
    int column = row + (sqrt % 1d > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    // To encrypt
    char[][] array = new char[row][column];

    for (int i = 0, cursor = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
        array[i % row][i / row] = cursor < str.length() ? str.charAt(cursor++) : 0;
    }

    //// Just a equivalent to above
    //for (int i = 0, cursor = 0; i < column; i++) {
    //    for (int j = 0; j < row; j++) {
    //        array[j][i] = cursor < str.length() ? str.charAt(cursor++) : 0;
    //    }
    //}

    // Print the encrypted array
    StringBuilder encrypted = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
        char c = array[i / column][i % column];
        System.out.print(c + ((i + 1) % column == 0 ? "\n" : " "));
        encrypted.append(c);
    }
    System.out.println("The encrypted string: " + encrypted);


    // To decrypt
    System.out.println();

    int decryptRow = array.length;
    if (decryptRow < 1) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Empty array");
    }

    StringBuilder decrypted = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < row * column; i++) {
        char c = array[i % row][i / row];
        System.out.print(c + ((i + 1) % row == 0 ? "\n" : " "));
        decrypted.append(c);
    }
    System.out.println("The decrypted string: " + decrypted);
```

Output:

```
P N T S
L T M A
A E E G
I X S E
The encrypted string: PNTSLTMAAEEGIXSE

P L A I
N T E X
T M E S
S A G E
The decrypted string: PLAINTEXTMESSAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know `numberOfColumns` and `numberOfRows` the following method will decrypt the message:

```
public String decrypt(int numberOfRows, int numberOfColumns, String encrypted) {
    String decrypted = "";
    for(int c = 0; c < numberOfColumns; c++) {
        for(int r = 0; r < numberOfRows; r++) {
            decrypted += encrypted.charAt(numberOfColumns * (r % numberOfRows) + (c % numberOfColumns));
        }
    }
    return decrypted;
 }
```